# Set cron job but the order email will auto cc to other customers

Tags: email, sales-order, cron

Set the cron job, but the order email will auto cc to other customers and I don't know why. Email configuration and setup are proper, and only  "order email " will be auto cc, the shipment,invoice email and account email didn't have this problem.
[image]